# Nuxt3 + Vite build with @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets

Tags: failed, vite, solana-wallets-vue, vue

Got a build problem, where I can not get the the app to build. It works fine locally but whenever I'm trying to build it get stuck on some import BS. Feels as if I tried almost everything at this point i.e. optimizedDeps, PolyFill, transpile etc. etc.
I'm using:
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.23",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-vue": "^0.4.5",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.19.26",
"solana-wallets-vue": "^0.6.1",

Error:

Directory import '/Insert/User/Desktop/project/.output/server/node_modules/jayson/lib/client/browser' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Insert/User/Desktop/project/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs
Did you mean to import jayson/lib/client/browser/index.js?